# Fatal Error Occurs while declaring Local variable in MYSQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am getting an exception while declaring the local variable in MYSQL. Please suggest me how to solve the issue..

Exception: 
Fatal error encountered during command execution. 
InnerException: 
`{"Parameter '@OrderofParent' must be defined."}`

Code Snippit:

```
   StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder(); <br>
    sbQuery.Append(@"Declare @OrderofParent INT; SET @OrderofParent = 0;
                    select top 1 @OrderofParent = OrderofParent from Filter group        by          OrderofParent order by OrderofParent desc;

    select 'FamilyType' as Mode, 0 as Id, 'Complexity Type' as FilterName, null as FilterCreatedDate, 0 as IsDisabled,0 as ParentId,                                               @OrderofParent as OrderofParent,1 as TagDisplay, 0 as ParentCount from I_FamilyTypePrice
union
Select 'Filter', Id, FilterName, FilterCreatedDate, IsDisabled, f.ParentId, OrderofParent, TagDisplay, 0 from Filter f where f.ParentID = 0 
union
select 'FamilyType', ft.Id, FamilyTypeName, CreatedDate, 0,0, @OrderofParent,0, count(complexityType) from I_FamilyTypePrice ft join Family f on f.complexityType = ft.Id where version = @version and IsActive = 1 and Uploaded = 1; ");
```

Comment: Where's the code that actually calls mySQL?

Answer (score 1):

ADD
`"Allow User Variables=True"` 
in the connection string parameter